# CORDIC acceleration in STM32 MCUs for motor control

Tags: microcontroller, motor, stm32, cordic

I'd like to implement the field-oriented control (FOC) algorithm on an STM32 MCU. At first I was going to use the STM32G4, which has a CORDIC accelerator. But then I found out that the G4 is old, and the latest high-performance MCUs are the STM32H7s.

But only one MCU in the H7 line, the STM32H735, has a CORDIC accelerator. Of course, I can't find a development board with that device.

So here's my question: is it worth going to a previous generation MCU (STM32G4) to get CORDIC for FOC? Or will the latest Cortex-M7 core run quickly enough that I can use traditional sin/cos functions?

Comment: G4 is not older than H7 nor is it a previous generation. If anything, G4 is newer than most variants of the H7. They are different lines with different target markets. Both MCUs have been unavailable for the last two years and the lead time has remained 52 weeks that entire time.

Comment: @DKNguyen The G4 has the Cortex-M4 core and the H7 has the Cortex-M7 core. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Cortex-M7), "The Cortex-M7 is a high-performance core with almost double the power efficiency of the older Cortex-M4". Looks older to me.

Comment: H7 came out in 2017 , G4 came out in 2019 . Define old? Because a lot of devices still using F4 that came out in 2011. You are comparing STM32 Microcontrollers and their age to Arm Cortex Cores and their age. 2 Different things.

Comment: if you want brute fore to do math functions dont look at ST when NXP has faster chips , that being said FoC has been done before with even slower and older chips, you'll be ok if its not the latest series, but if you must have the latest series,  the cortex M(single digit) are not the latest fastest most efficient, instead look at M33, M35P, M55 M85

Comment: @user934904 Less powerful \$\ne\$ old. Nor does powerful (high throughput) \$=\$ low latency.